# OpenLayers.Format.CQL Regex Problem

Tags: openlayers-2, internationalization, regular-expression

I have a cql filter as SQL. Im trying to parse this cql to OpenLayers.Filter using OpenLayers.Format.CQL.read() method. It all works fine since my input is ascii. When I type Turkish characters as VALUE an error occurs. I modifed regex belong to VALUE property in CQL.js as /(^('.+'|\d+(.\d*)?|.\d+))/
Now it accepts non-ascii characters but generated Filter is wrong. The regex i modified might affect somewhere.

What i try and what message i get actually like follow

```
var format_cql = new OpenLayers.Format.CQL;
format_cql.read("NAME = 'ŞAKİR'");
```

Error: ERROR: In parsing: ['ŞAKİR'], expected one of: VALUE: /^('\w+'|\d+(.\d*)?|.\d+)/

If i type SAKIR instead of ŞAKİR it returns a OpenLayers Comparison object well.
It also doesnt allow to type space character in value.

Could someone please help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

My friend helped me and changed regex of 'value' property in CQL.js as
/^('([^ \t-~]|\w|\s)*'|\d+(.\d*)?|.\d+)/i
It works well with unicode characters and spaces.
Fyi.